# CSS Zooming Out

Tags: html, css

I am new to webdesign and have my very first website. Howevever when I zoom out the design breaks apart. Especially Seach box and featured images. I know there are lots of similiar questions and answers however I am so newbie that I am unable to adapt one. I need specific instructions to do that.

Site: http://www.alphabitrage.com
Code: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3704b07a027426208738

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. A few suggestions - Firstly, try to avoid linking to external links as the links may at some point no longer be available. Try to show the specific code you are working on, don't expect us to go through your entire code base. An easy way is: this is what I have, this is what I'm trying to accomplish, and this is the short set of code that I think is linked to the effect I want to create.

Comment: If you are implementing RWD then have all your widths in %. You have #searchbarleft width to 430px but some auto width elements or % width elements wont like it. Put all in % and use CSS box-model as well along with it helps when you have static paddings /margins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy: remove `width: 430px` from this CSS selector:

```css
#searchbarleft {
  /*width: 430px;*/
  float: left;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

It doesn’t seem to have any positive effect anyway, so just remove it.

Answer (score 0):

For example, I take your search block. You have `id="searchformfix"` and `width: 430px`. When you zoom out in some browsers you have no space to collect all you block, then they go under other blocks. To fix it you should make some extra free space to you main block (it's a block which contain other smaller blocks). For `id="searchformfix"` I make a `width: 450px` and everything works fine!

Comment: Thanks, I tried to below first and it worked but I am sure this one will work as well.

Comment: Also when you zoom to 25% out your page you still have other blocks which crashes, try to make the same with others blocks!

Comment: Yes you are right. I am trying to find them now.

Comment: For that instances, I used percentages in width and seems that it is working. Thanks

Comment: @αBitrage you're welcome!